# Avoiding retain cycles in swift without restricting what can conform to a protocol

Tags: ios, swift, reference, delegates, swift-protocols

Let's say I have two components in Swift that need instances of each other.

```swift
protocol P { }

struct S : P {
    var foo: Foo

    init(withFoo foo: Foo) {
        self.foo = foo
        foo.p = self
    }
}

class C : P {
    var foo: Foo

    init(withFoo foo: Foo) {
        self.foo = foo
        foo.p = self
    }
}

class Foo {
    var p: P? = nil
}
```

A `Foo` refers to a `P`, and the two types that conform to `P` refer to a `Foo`.  Note that `C` is a reference type and `S` is a value type.

But instantiating a `C` creates a retain cycle since the `C` and the `Foo` store strong references to each other.  This will result in a memory leak.

I can avoid this by declaring `Foo.p` as a `weak var`: `weak var p: P? = nil`.  But doing so results in an error: `'weak' must not be applied to non-class-bound 'P'; consider adding a protocol conformance that has a class bound`.  I'm then required to make `P` a class-bound protocol: `protocol P : class { }`.  But this results in another error: `Non-class type 'S' cannot conform to class protocol 'P'`.  A struct cannot conform to a class-bound protocol.

It seems that Swift is forcing me to either prevent structs from conforming to `P` or risk memory leaks.  But what if I really want a struct that conforms to `P`?  I can't make `P` extend `class` or make `Foo.p` a `weak var`.  And then, the compiler has no way of guaranteeing that I won't assign an instance of `C` to `Foo.p`, which would create a memory leak.

How can I guarantee that these interdependent types will not cause a memory leak while also being able to declare structs that conform to `P`?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34493644/swift-delegate-protocol-cannot-prevent-retain-cycle-issue?rq=1  ?